# Planet rotate around its local y-axis using Matrix4x4

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to rotate a sphere (planet) from a starting static position around it's local y-axis using a Matrix4x4 with custom rotation formulas. The planet doesn't rotate at all. I've posted the code below. Thanks for any advice.

Note: ori would be the degrees per second it would rotate

```
void OrientationRate()
{
    Matrix4x4 o = new Matrix4x4();
    float theta = ori * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    o[0, 0] = Mathf.Cos(theta);
    o[0, 2] = -Mathf.Sin(theta);
    o[2, 0] = Mathf.Sin(theta);
    o[2, 2] = Mathf.Cos(theta);

    Vector4 p = this.transform.eulerAngles;
    p.w = 1;

    Vector4 pprime = (o * p);

    //set the new position
    this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(pprime.z, pprime.x, pprime.y) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you must use a Matrix4x4? If it's not mandatory, seems you could do this with a call to `this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * theta)`. Also, you are multiplying `Time.fixedDeltaTime` twice into your rotation vector which is probably incorrect (it's enough to factor it in once, as you do when calculating `theta`). `Transform.Rotate` works on local coordinates unless specified otherwise: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html .

Comment: It's for a class assignment so we learn about matrix math. I know I could use the built in functions but we aren't allowed to. Also, thanks for the delta time advice, I totally didn't notice lol

Comment: SO community is not keen on assisting with assignments. Anyhow, transformation matrices belong to the Maths domain, you'd be better off asking exactly what you don't understand on http://maths.stackexchange.com.